# A Question Pertaining to the Countability/Uncountability of Certain Infinite Sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Why “set of real numbers between [0,0.1)” is uncountable?

According to Cantor theorem Natural number is countable.Other than this integers sometimes called as countable set. I know real number can go upto any limit and hence uncountable. But here range is given. So, why not is it still countable?

If real number can be uncountable, then can we say integers(not always, like range of integer not given) or rational number be uncountable?

Comment: Natural numbers, integers and rational numbers are countable, but intervals of real numbers can be put in correspondence with real numbers, which are uncountable

Comment: You need to learn the _definitions_ of countable and uncountable.

Comment: definition is this "In mathematics, a countable set is a set with the same cardinality (number of elements) as some subset of the set of natural numbers. A countable set is either a finite set or a countably infinite set.",right?

Comment: "I know real number can go upto any limit and hence uncountable." This is not the reason why $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.

Comment: "I know real number can go upto any limit and hence uncountable."  That is not what uncountable/countable means.  I think you need to go back the the texts and reread.  Countable means the elements of the set can be listed one after another.  It has nothing to do with limits.  The integers and the rational numbers are countable and can be listed one after another.  Cantor's diagonal argument shows the reals can not be.  It also shows $[0,1)$ can not be. If we multiply each number by $.1$ then $[0,1)$ can be listed if $[0,.1)$ can be.  But $[0,1)$ can not be so $[0,0.1)$ can not be either.

Comment: ""In mathematics, a countable set is a set with the same cardinality (number of elements) as some subset of the set of natural numbers. A countable set is either a finite set or a countably infinite set.",  Yes, but you don't understand what this *means*.  That's what *learning* a definition means.

Comment: " I know real number can go upto any limit" has nothing to do with " "In mathematics, a countable set is a set with the same cardinality (number of elements) as some subset of the set of natural numbers. A countable set is either a finite set or a countably infinite set."

Answer (score 1):

Countable is different from bounded (limited "range").  Elements of a countable set, such as integers or rational numbers, can be put in correspondence with the natural numbers, even though none of those sets is bounded.  On the other hand, elements of intervals of real numbers -- even intervals that are bounded, such as $[0,0.1)$ -- can be put in correspondence with elements of the set of real numbers, which are uncountable.

Answer (score 1):

There are many proofs of this fact.  Clearly the points in $[0, 0.1)$ can be placed in a one-to-one correspondence with the uncountable real numbers in $(10, \infty )$ by the map $1/x$.

Comment: I think you meant $(10,\infty)$, but your argument is well-taken

Answer (score 1):

A set is countable if and only if it can be put in a 1-1 correspondence with the set of counting (natural) numbers. Using Cantor's notion of a 1-1 correspondence and a little bit of mathematical ingenuity, it can be shown that the set of rational numbers (and every subset thereof) is countable.

On the other hand, this cannot be done with the set of reals. Cantor, using what is now his famous "Diagonal Argument," showed that the set of real numbers between $0$ and $1$ is not countable, and, thus, neither is the set of reals.